# Eliminar caracteres cadena java

Tags: java, string

Tengo un problema al trabajar la respuesta a una petición al servidor. La respuesta del servidor es un string con el formato:

```
$ServerResponse = ["2022-11-09","2022-11-16","2022-11-23",...etc];
```

Yo necesito almacenar en un array cada una de las fechas con el formato 2022-11-09,para poder trabajar más tarde con ellas. De momento he provado con:

```
String $Server = ServerResponse.("\"", "");
String[] fechas = Server.split(",");
```

Esto me funciona con las comillas pero no hay forma de eliminar los caracteres [ y ]
he provado con `Server.replace("\[", "");` pero no me funciona...

Alguna idea? Gracias.

Despues

Comment: Cómo quieres que sea tu resultado? no termino de entender bien

Comment: Intenta con `replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");`

Comment: Gracias @Dramaturgo, si respondes con tu comentario doy por valida la respuesta!